# JAXB returning null for a nested xml containing collections

Tags: java, jaxb

I want to unmarshall the following xml into another a parent object as defined below. But it always returns NULL.

Incoming XML:

```
<contentFiles>
<contentFile>
<contentFileName>cwb_reg_content_IB20C0F504A9A11E281E4C8BF76F4977C.pdf</contentFileName>
<title><![CDATA[SEC No-Action Guidance Expanding the Definition of “Ready Market” for Certain Foreign Equity Securities]]></title>
<sourcePublicationDate>20121219</sourcePublicationDate>
<alternateDocNumbers>
  <alternateDocNumber>12345-b</alternateDocNumber>
</alternateDocNumbers>
<citesAffected>
   <cite>SEA Rule 15c3-1</cite>
</citesAffected>
</contentFile>
</contentFiles>
```

Parent class corresponding to `<contentFiles>`

```
 @XmlRootElement(name = "contentFiles")
    public class RtSuperQuickMetadata
    {
        private List<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem> rtSuperQuickMetadataItems;

        public RtSuperQuickMetadata()
        {
            rtSuperQuickMetadataItems = new ArrayList<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem>();
        }

        public List<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem> getRtSuperQuickMetadataItems()
        {
            return rtSuperQuickMetadataItems;
        }

        public void setRtSuperQuickMetadataItems(
            List<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem> rtSuperQuickMetadataItems)
        {
            this.rtSuperQuickMetadataItems = rtSuperQuickMetadataItems;
        }

    }
```

Parent class corresponding to `<contentFile>`

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "contentFile")
public class RtSuperQuickMetadataItem
{
    private String contentFileName;
    private String title;
    private String sourcePublicationDate;
    private List<AlternateDocNumber> alternateDocNumbers;
    private List<Cite> citesAffected;

    public RtSuperQuickMetadataItem()
    {
        alternateDocNumbers = new ArrayList<AlternateDocNumber>();
        citesAffected = new ArrayList<Cite>();
    }


    public List<AlternateDocNumber> getAlternateDocNumbers()
    {
        return alternateDocNumbers;
    }


    public List<Cite> getCitesAffected()
    {
        return citesAffected;
    }


    public String getContentFileName()
    {
        return contentFileName;
    }


    public String getSourcePublicationDate()
    {
        return sourcePublicationDate;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }


    public void setAlternateDocNumbers(List<AlternateDocNumber> alternateDocNumbers)
    {
        this.alternateDocNumbers = alternateDocNumbers;
    }


    public void setCitesAffected(List<Cite> citesAffected)
    {
        this.citesAffected = citesAffected;
    }


    public void setContentFileName(String contentFileName)
    {
        this.contentFileName = contentFileName;
    }


    public void setSourcePublicationDate(String sourcePublicationDate)
    {
        this.sourcePublicationDate = sourcePublicationDate;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

}


@XmlRootElement(name = "alternateDocNumber")
class AlternateDocNumber
{
    private String alternateDocNumber;

    public String getAlternateDocNumber()
    {
        return alternateDocNumber;
    }

    public void setAlternateDocNumber(String alternateDocNumber)
    {
        this.alternateDocNumber = alternateDocNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "AlternateDocNumber [alternateDocNumber=" + alternateDocNumber + "]";
    }
}


@XmlRootElement(name = "cite")
class Cite
{
    private String cite;

    public String getCite()
    {
        return cite;
    }

    public void setCite(String cite)
    {
        this.cite = cite;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Cite [cite=" + cite + "]";
    }
}
```

Unmarshaller code using JAXB:

```
public RtSuperQuickMetadata unmarshallXml(final File metadataFile)
        throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        RtSuperQuickMetadata rtSuperQuickMetadata = null;
        try
        {
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(RtSuperQuickMetadata.class);

            Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            rtSuperQuickMetadata =
                (RtSuperQuickMetadata) um.unmarshal(metadataFile);
        }
        catch (JAXBException e)
        {
            String msg = "Malformed XML supplied as Metadata" + " Msg " + e.getMessage();
            LOG.error(msg, e);
            throw new RuntimeException(msg, e);
        }

        return rtSuperQuickMetadata;
    }
```

Comment: Not really an answer but a general suggestion.  I would take the schema and run xjc on it to generate the JAXB classes instead of annotating them by hand.  Even if you don't decide to use them you can at least get a good idea of what the marshaller is expecting.  In practice I've found it much easier to have your model objects generated at build time by XJC.

Comment: can you give an example where I can look up this technique and implement it ?

Comment: @Phoenix Usually to get an idea on how my XML will look like, I will create my object structure in code and use the Marshaller to print to System.out. I will update my answer to show this.

Comment: @Phoenix What are you using to build your project?  Ant, Maven, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many `XmlRootElements`, you generally want to use this with the top element only. What you want to do is label the children as `XmlElement`.

Remove the `XmlRootElement` annotation from all but your root element (i.e. `RtSuperQuickMetadata`), and label them with `XmlElement` *in the class from which they will be loaded*.

So, as an example, here is how your `RtSuperQuickMetadata` class should look:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "contentFiles")
class RtSuperQuickMetadata
{
    private List<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem> rtSuperQuickMetadataItems;

    public RtSuperQuickMetadata()
    {
        rtSuperQuickMetadataItems = new ArrayList<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem>();
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "contentFile")
    public List<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem> getRtSuperQuickMetadataItems()
    {
        return rtSuperQuickMetadataItems;
    }

    public void setRtSuperQuickMetadataItems(
            List<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem> rtSuperQuickMetadataItems)
    {
        this.rtSuperQuickMetadataItems = rtSuperQuickMetadataItems;
    }

}
```

Transfer this principle to `alternateDocNumbers` and `citesAffected` as well.

---

If you want to see an example of how the `Unmarshaller` thinks your XML is formatted based off your annotations, you can create your structure in code and use the `Marshaller`. Here is a quick and ugly example:

```
RtSuperQuickMetadata rtSuperQuickMetadata = new RtSuperQuickMetadata();

List<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem> rtSuperQuickMetadataItems = new ArrayList<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem>();
rtSuperQuickMetadata.setRtSuperQuickMetadataItems(rtSuperQuickMetadataItems);

RtSuperQuickMetadataItem item = new RtSuperQuickMetadataItem();
rtSuperQuickMetadataItems.add(item);

ArrayList<Cite> cites = new ArrayList<Cite>();
Cite cite = new Cite();
cite.setCiteStr("MyCite");
cites.add(cite);
item.setCitesAffected(cites);

Marshaller m = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
m.marshal(rtSuperQuickMetadata, System.out);
```

This will output the result to `System.out`. You can put this in a file instead, whatever suits your needs.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! I had another question. Why doesn't jaxb automatically allocate memory for the lists contained in the object. Why do we need to assign memory in a constructor for it ?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know the answer to your question. My best guess is because we use interfaces when declaring our variables therefore JAXB has no knowledge of the actual implementation of the `List` to use. That is where we come in to say: use `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Phoenix - You do not need to pre-initialize values for `List` properties.

Comment: While unmarshalling these items the following isn't being saved into the metadata object. <citesAffected><cite>12</cite></citesAffected> I need to add another element for this to be generated ??

Comment: @Phoenix - You can use the following annotations on `getCitesAffected()`, `@XmlElementWrapper(name="citesAffected")` and `@XmlElement(name="cite")` - see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Comment: @Phoenix the reason being is because of the `cite` variable within you `Cite` class. In order to populate this particular varaible, your XML would have to look like: `<cites> <cite> <cite> SEA Rule 15c3-1 </cite> </cite> </cites>`

Answer (score 1):

I have added this answer to address the follow up questions you posted as comments on the [**answer given by cklab**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14715556/383861).

> I had another question. Why doesn't jaxb automatically allocate memory
>   for the lists contained in the object. Why do we need to assign memory
>   in a constructor for it ?

You do not need to, see below.

> While unmarshalling these items the following isn't being saved into
>   the metadata object. 12 I
>   need to add another element for this to be generated ??

See mapping below.

**RtSuperQuickMetadata**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "contentFiles")
public class RtSuperQuickMetadata {

    private List<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem> rtSuperQuickMetadataItems;

    @XmlElement(name="contentFile")
    public List<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem> getRtSuperQuickMetadataItems() {
        return rtSuperQuickMetadataItems;
    }

    public void setRtSuperQuickMetadataItems(
            List<RtSuperQuickMetadataItem> rtSuperQuickMetadataItems) {
        this.rtSuperQuickMetadataItems = rtSuperQuickMetadataItems;
    }

}
```

**RtSuperQuickMetadataItem**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(propOrder={"contentFileName", "title", "sourcePublicationDate", "alternateDocNumbers", "citesAffected"})
public class RtSuperQuickMetadataItem {
    private String contentFileName;
    private String title;
    private String sourcePublicationDate;
    private List<AlternateDocNumber> alternateDocNumbers;
    private List<Cite> citesAffected;

    public List<AlternateDocNumber> getAlternateDocNumbers() {
        return alternateDocNumbers;
    }

    public List<Cite> getCitesAffected() {
        return citesAffected;
    }

    public String getContentFileName() {
        return contentFileName;
    }

    public String getSourcePublicationDate() {
        return sourcePublicationDate;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setAlternateDocNumbers(
            List<AlternateDocNumber> alternateDocNumbers) {
        this.alternateDocNumbers = alternateDocNumbers;
    }

    public void setCitesAffected(List<Cite> citesAffected) {
        this.citesAffected = citesAffected;
    }

    public void setContentFileName(String contentFileName) {
        this.contentFileName = contentFileName;
    }

    public void setSourcePublicationDate(String sourcePublicationDate) {
        this.sourcePublicationDate = sourcePublicationDate;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

**AlternateDocNumber**

```
class AlternateDocNumber {

    private String alternateDocNumber;

    public String getAlternateDocNumber() {
        return alternateDocNumber;
    }

    public void setAlternateDocNumber(String alternateDocNumber) {
        this.alternateDocNumber = alternateDocNumber;
    }

}
```

**Cite**

```
class Cite {

    private String cite;

    public String getCite() {
        return cite;
    }

    public void setCite(String cite) {
        this.cite = cite;
    }

}
```